# MYSQL: How can I find 'last monday's date' (performance Issue)

Tags: mysql, date

is there a simpler way than writing:

select **date_sub(curdate(), interval WEEKDAY(curdate()) day)**  as LastMonday 
from dual

Comment: I think that that is as simple as you will get it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're not using an ancient MySQL, you can wrap this in a stored function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `LastMonday`() RETURNS DATETIME    
  RETURN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) ;
```

and then call

```
select LastMonday() as LastMonday
```

**Update:**

If you're having performance problems, you can persist the value in a session variable. That way you can be sure that it will only be calculated once.

```
set @LastMonday=LastMonday();
select @Lastmonday;
```

*(in this simple query it makes no difference of course...)*

Comment: that's exactly how I had "avoided" the long looking date calculations up to now ... I was/am worried about potential overhead ...

Comment: I've since added your "performance update" suggestion to our codebase. It makes a huge difference, somehow I'd expected the function be called only once .. (but how is the optimizer to know I'm not returning time in milliseconds ..)

Comment: The trick here is that the value is calculated once and then cached manually. You could try what the optimizer does. It might be smart enough to cache it too, but you can't really rely on it.

Comment: If today is monday, this will return today

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @dateCurrent = CURDATE();
SET @dateCurrentDayInWeek = DAYOFWEEK(@dateCurrent) - 2;
SET @dateLastMonday = DATE_ADD(@dateCurrent, INTERVAL -@dateCurrentDayInWeek DAY);

SELECT @dateLastMonday;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return on a Sunday the *next* Monday, instead of the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to set a variable for showing the last monday:

```
SET @lastMonday = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY);
```

and call it with:

```
SELECT @lastMonday
```

*(inspired in the user Wouter van Nifterick)*

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-- Today is 05 April 2013

-- Get Last Monday from MySQL

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()) - ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) - 7) % 7), '%Y-%m-%d') last_monday;

-- Output

last_monday  
-------------
2013-04-29
```

Comment: For me that's neither simpler, nor more performant than the code in the question? .. but I'll take the hint and will re-phrase the question title!

Comment: For me, this outputs not next Monday but the Monday after that.