# MYSQL - find nearest previous day

Tags: mysql

can I somehow (without using PHP) find nearest previous date of day in week?

Like:

**What is date of nearest previous tuesday?**

Comment: You mean find the last tuesday? The real last tuesday or the last tuesday in a date column?

Comment: MYSQL: How can I find 'last monday's date' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270850/mysql-how-can-i-find-last-mondays-date

Comment: real last tuesday, @Vache thanks, i'll look

Comment: @Marek You just need to add a -1 to that expression: `SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())-1) DAY);

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY( CURDATE() ) - wday +
          IF( WEEKDAY( CURDATE() ) > wday, 0, 7 ) DAY
```

`wday` is the weekday you want ( 0 Monday, 1 Tuesday, ... )

for the same weekday as today this returns today itself, if you want it to return previous week's day change `>` to `>=`.