# Get weekdays based on timezone and current time

Tags: mysql

I am having below table structure where day_index 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday and 6 = Sunday. Here start_time and end_time is UTC Time.

```
day_index  hour_string          start_time  end_time
        0  05:30 AM - 05:30 PM  07:30 PM    07:30 AM
        1  10:00 AM - 08:00 PM  12:00 AM    10:00 AM
        2  07:30 AM - 11:30 PM  09:30 PM    01:30 PM
        3  09:00 AM - 02:30 PM  11:00 PM    04:30 AM
        4  09:00 AM - 04:00 PM  11:00 PM    06:00 AM
        5  08:30 AM - 03:30 PM  10:30 PM    05:30 AM
        6  08:30 AM - 11:00 PM  10:30 PM    01:00 PM
```

Now based on today's time i need whole weekday like today we have 22-07-2020 so it would be 20-07-2020,21-07-2020 and last one is 27-07-2020.

Also if today times is over ( end_time with timezone ) i need next available day with start_time.

**Example** : In today's case we have 1.30 PM UTC +  5.30 = 6.30. So we have next opening time would be 11.00 PM UTC + 5.30 = 4.30 AM In Morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with CONVERT_TZ?  That is how you convert a datetime to another timezone.  You cannot convert a time without the date to a timezone.

Here are some variables to set before running the query;

```
SET @last_monday = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY);
SET @local_timezone = 'US/Eastern';
```

This query will give you the date for each day of the week, the start and end time in UTC, and the start and end time in the local timezone:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(@last_monday, INTERVAL day_index DAY) date_dayofweek,
TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(@last_monday, INTERVAL day_index DAY),' ',start_time)) startDateTimeUTC,
TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(@last_monday, INTERVAL day_index DAY),' ',end_time)) endDateTimeUTC,
CONVERT_TZ(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(@last_monday, INTERVAL day_index DAY),' ',start_time)),'UTC',@local_timezone) startDateTimeLocal,
CONVERT_TZ(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_ADD(@last_monday, INTERVAL day_index DAY),' ',end_time)),'UTC',@local_timezone) endDateTimeLocal
FROM table_name ;
```

Using the answer here to get last Monday -
[MYSQL: How can I find 'last monday's date' (performance Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270850/mysql-how-can-i-find-last-mondays-date-performance-issue)

You can also use variables within the query to make this query much more readable, as there is a lot of repetition.  I'm not sure if that would be confusing for you, but I'm happy to provide you with a query if you would need it.

Answer (score -1):

This was a tricky mysql query but with the help of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538854/mysql-select-date-of-current-weeks-monday) it is quite staightforward to answear.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),
            INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY),
        INTERVAL day_index DAY)
FROM
    schedule
```

Comment: Edited my question for more understanding